# Chained methods reflection execution

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to execute some chained methods using reflection.

What I´m trying to get is an IQueryable of a Entity Core DBContext Set of an unknown compile type:

```
var type = typeof(x);
this.DBContext.Set(type).AsQueryable();
```

Obviously, that code does not compile because Set is a generic Method where the type must be defined in compile time:

```
this.DBContext.Set<TUnknownType>().AsQueryable();
```

To solve that, I tried to execute the methods using reflection:

```
    MethodInfo dbSetMethod = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set));
    MethodInfo generic = dbSetMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.DeclaringType);

    var asQueryableMethod = generic.ReturnType.GetMethod("AsQueryable");
    var result = asQueryableMethod.Invoke(this.DbContext, null);
```

But when I debug the code, I get a null in the line:

```
var asQueryableMethod = generic.ReturnType.GetMethod("AsQueryable");
```

Apparently, the `dbContext.Set<TUnknownType>()` does not have the AsQueryable method. That method is an extension method coming from Linq I guess.

What am I missing? Why is the method unavailable?

Comment: When you say _of a dynamic type_ what exactly do you mean?  Late bound dynamic type, closed generic type, runtime only type?

Comment: Why the downvote? Its a clear question. Dynamic type means an unknown type until runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a generic extension method with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927028/how-to-call-a-generic-extension-method-with-reflection)

Answer (score 3):

That's right, `DbSet<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>`, which exposes `AsQueryable<T>()` [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003(v=vs.110).aspx).

C# offers two ways to invoke an extension method - as an instance method, i.e.

```
this.DBContext.Set<UnknownType>().AsQueryable();
```

or as a static method, i.e.

```
Queryable.AsQueryable(this.DBContext.Set<UnknownType>());
```

Reflection APIs, on the other hand, support only the second approach, i.e. the static method way of obtaining and invoking the method. You should get `MethodInfo` for generic `Queryable.AsQueryable`, and pass it an appropriate generic type parameter to make a `MethodInfo` object suitable for invocation.

Comment: To put it into other words: The first way is syntactic sugar, resolved by the compiler, for the second way.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I was trying, but how can I pass the dbSetGeneric method as a parameter to the Queryable.AsQueryable() method? I´ve been trying but can´t get it working.

Comment: @Andres Get method info for `Queryable.AsQueryable` with one argument. Call `MakeGenericMethod` on it, passing `property.DeclaringType` for the argument. You should be able to invoke the resultant `MethodInfo`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I already got the method like this: `MethodInfo asQueryableMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "AsQueryable" && !x.IsGenericMethod).First();` But its argument is a generic method info. I need to create a methodinfo representing this: `Queryable.AsQueryable(this.DBContext.Set<Type>());`. How can I pass that `Set<>()` method as a parameter?