# How to get special MemberInfo of List<>

Tags: c#, generics

Below is code fragments

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace DetailTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        PropertyInfo pi = a.GetType().GetProperty("cs");
        MemberInfo[] mis = pi.PropertyType.GetMembers();
        MemberInfo[] mis2 = mis.Where(d => d.Name.StartsWith("A")).ToArray();
        foreach (MemberInfo mi in mis2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mi);
        }
    }
}

class A
{
    B _b = new B();
    public B b { get{return _b;}}
    public List<C> cs{get;set;}
}
}
```

I just want to get `Any` method, but I got nothing. Why?
I mean how to get Any method of List type?

ps: I really reference System.Linq

Comment: [`Any` is a LINQ extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs#L11-L45), if you remove `using System.Linq` you will see it's no longer available when you type `cs.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a generic extension method with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927028/how-to-call-a-generic-extension-method-with-reflection)

Comment: [Another duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection)

Comment: If you don't understand what extension methods are, you can check out the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I invoke an extension method using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452261/how-do-i-invoke-an-extension-method-using-reflection)

Comment: As John said, the Any method is not a method of the List type.  Rather, it is an extension method that work on any type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  As suggested in other comments, read more about extension methods and look at the linked answers to gain further enlightenment.