# How to simulate List<T>.Any method via MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection, generic-list

I try to simulate `List<T>.Any` method via `MethodInfo`.
First I define a class:

```
class Test
{
    int _value;
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Test(int v)
    {
        _value = v;
    }
}
```

..and then I create a `List<Test>`

```
List<C> list = new List<C>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new C(i));
}
```

My aim to call `list.Any(c=>c.Value>3)` via MethodInfo, now I met the problem about how to locate the real method. I can find Any() method in `System.Linq.Enumerable` and `System.Linq.Queryable`.

When I check the definition about List<>, I think I should use the method in `System.Linq.Enumerable`, because it implements IEnumerable, is it right?

Now I have a new question if a class implements both IEnumerable and IQueryable, which MethodInfo should I use, such as Any(), Sum(), and so on.

Comment: How is `List<Test>` and `List<C>` in your code related? Furthermore you should use the `Enumerable` methods.

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`. Usually you'll want to go from the more specific to the less specific. So use `System.Linq.Queryable` if you can, then fallback on `System.Linq.Enumerable`

Comment: You are talking about `Any` as if its an instance method, but it's extension method ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any)). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15927145/1997232) how to invoke it.

Comment: Which `MethodInfo` to use depends on which method you want to call and why.